# Displaying yii2 filterboxes fails in a custom function column

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a grid that i would like to filter but the filter boxes are not enabled in the column

This is the grid row

```
[
    'attribute'=>'  category',
    'value'=>function($model){
        switch ($model->category){
            case 1:{
                return "Normal truck";
            }
            case 2:{
                return "Bulker truck";
            }
        }
    },
    'filter'=>array(1=>"Normal truck",2=>"Bulker truck"),  //the dropdown filter
],
```

And this is my grid configuration

```
echo DynaGrid::widget([
'columns' => $columns,
'showPersonalize' => true,
//'allowThemeSetting'=> false,
'options' => ['id' => 'company_truck_grid'],
'gridOptions' => [
    'options' => ['id' => 'company_grid_trcl_inside'],
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel, //filter is set
    ............
]
 ]);
```

This is whats being displayed
[image]

As you can see the category column has no dropdown filter and is disabled.. Where am i wrong..

Comment: What about `Truck number` and `Transporter`? If they're working, you should do similar thing to `Category` as well. :)

Comment: Why are there two spaces in attribute's name? `'attribute'=>'  category'`

Comment: Edvin thats the same thing i have done to them

Comment: Bizley it was a mistype.. Thanks it now works